# Как убрать символы-сущности при генерации XML

Tags: php, xml

В текст встречаются всякие символы-картинки, например  
При генерации XML  я получаю ошибку при валидации. В NOTEPAD данные символы отображаются так 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как исправить данный момент ?

Comment: Например, через регулярное выражение заменять все символы, какие не подходят на пустые - replace("^[a-z0-9\<\>\/]", "", xml); (регулярное выражение, как пример и оно не точное).

Comment: я полагаю, что это не совсем правильно, учитывая, что я не знаю всех "запрещенных" символов